# How can I test an <svg> with a <use> tag using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, svg, jestjs, react-testing-library

```html
<span className={containerClassName} data-testid="iconId">
  <svg role="img" className={svgClassName}>
    <use href="#iconhref" />
    <title>iconTitle</title>
  </svg>
  iconText
</span>
```

I have the above html and I wanted to write some unit test's using React testing library without using the container from render. Thanks

Suggestions needed as I am trying to avoid container from render in order to access the use tag such as
expect(document.querySelector('use').getAttribute('href')).toEqual('#iconhref')

Current test's

```
// icon should be visible in the document along with it's title
expect(screen.getByRole('img')).toBeVisible();
expect(screen.getByTitle('iconTitle')).toBeInTheDocument();

// icon should have a href attribute along with it's target
expect(screen.getByTestId('iconId')).toHaveAttribute('href', '#iconhref');
```

Comment: Small note: ``href={`#iconhref`}`` is really silly, just use `href="#iconhref"`. But more importantly: what do you expect this to _do_? Because `<use>` takes copies of elements _from the same SVG document_ and your SVG does not have anything with that `id`. Is there another SVG you're not showing with an element that has `iconhref` as `id` attribute?

Comment: Im a bit confused, what do you mean by "from render"? Do you mean the users point of view?

Comment: Can you add more context to what is it that you are trying to test/assert?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. In general I just want to have a brief Idea about how to use the <use> in an svg, my current test's are as above(edited the question with current test's), but wasn't sure if this is the best approach

Comment: @Anthony I edited the question with my current test's

Comment: @Avi I edited the question above with my current test's

Comment: You're mixing HTML and SVG here. `getByTitle` looks for an element with that title _attribute_, not an element called `<title>`. Also, I simply don't undetstand what you _actually_ want to do, because the code you're showing "does nothing" as it were. What are you trying to achieve (as in, what do you want to do that that you wrote this code for. You don't want to have an idea about `<use>`, you want to use it for something: what is that something and why did you pick this code as solution to that? And then please explain that in your post, not in a comment).